# Calculated fields in table

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-7, calculated-field

I'm trying to create a calculated field (`Cost`) in a database table for values entered by the user for example price and quantity like in the example below :

```
Cost = Price * Quantity
```

I searched but I couldn't find a clear way how to it.

Comment: What does *Database Desktop* have to do with creating a calculated field in Delphi? Calculated fields are created using the Fields Editor from the form designer in the IDE. (I could be wrong, though; *Database Desktop* is related to the BDE, which has been dead for a decade, and I stopped using it long before it finally died.)

Comment: Is this a legacy software or a new software you're working on? If it's a new software, you should *not* be using BDE - it only exists for backwards compatibility for legacy software.

Comment: @KenWhite i used Database Desktop to creat a database table (sorry im new with delphi)

Comment: Calculated fields are used within Delphi, not Database Desktop (as I mentioned above). See the answer below.

Comment: If BDE was alive when D7 was released, and asker is using D7, isn't using BDE reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a calculated field from the Field Editor.

- Double click the *TTable* or *TQuery* to open the *Fields Editor*.
- Right click the *Fields Editor*, and choose *New Field* from the popup menu (or press <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd>).
- In the *New Field* dialog, give the field a name (such as 'Cost') and type (perhaps `Currency`), and check the radio button for *Calculated*, and then click *OK*.
- With the *TTable* or *TQuery* selected, choose the *Events* tab in the *Object Inspector*, find the *OnCalcFields* event, and double-click it to create the new empty event handler in the *Code Editor*.
- Add something similar to the code below, adjusting as needed for your field names:

  ```
  procedure TCustForm.yourQueryCalcField(DataSet : TDataset);
  begin
    DataSet.FieldByName('Cost').AsCurrency :=  
          DataSet.FieldByName('Price').AsCurrency* 
          DataSet.FieldByName('Quantity').AsInteger;
  end;
  ```

Comment: im stuck in (TCustForm.yourQueryCalcField) what should i put there ?   edit: i used a TTable and not a Tquery

Comment: @FerhatBoutaleb select your table, on the Object Inspector window click Events tab and double click OnCalcFields event area, you will see the code that generated by IDE.